Simplifying table-based code (lua)
In this example, we search for circles that are tangent to both a given circle and a line, demonstrating that their centers lie on a parabola. I'm using two tables, but one of them contains part of the other. Is it possible to avoid this repetition?
The tables are list and points. The latter contains the centers of the circles, while the former contains both the centers and the points of tangency of the circles.
 % !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[mini]{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{tkz-elements}
\makeatletter
\def\tkzPlotCoordinates{\pgfutil@ifnextchar[{\tkz@PlotCoordinates}{\tkz@PlotCoordinates[]}}
\def\tkz@PlotCoordinates[#1]#2{%
\draw[#1] plot coordinates {\directlua{tex.print(#2)}};}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\directlua{
scale =.5
z.O = point : new (0,0)
z.P = point : new (0,6)
z.M = point : new (0,3)
z.I = point : new (1,0)
C.PM = circle : new (z.P,z.M)
list = {}
points = {}
 for t = -0.24, 0.24, 0.004 do
 if (t> - 0.002 and t< 0.002) then else
     z.A = C.PM : point (t)
     L.OI = line : new (z.O,z.I)
     L.PA = line : new (z.P,z.A)
     z.C = intersection (L.OI,L.PA)
     L.tgt = C.PM : tangent_at (z.A)
     z.X = intersection (L.tgt,L.OI)
     z.o = bisector (z.X,z.A,z.C).pb
     table.insert (points, "("..z.o.re..","..z.o.im..")")
     table.insert (list,z.o.re.."/"..z.o.im.."/"..z.A.re.."/"..z.A.im)
   end
   end
    list = table.concat(list,",")
 }

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzGetNodes
\tkzPlotCoordinates[smooth,blue]{points}
     \foreach[expand list] \r/\s/\u/\v in {\directlua{tex.print({list})}}
{
  \tkzDefPoint(\u,\v){A}
  \tkzDefPoint(\r,\s){o}
  \tkzDrawCircle(o,A)
  \tkzDrawPoints[red,size=.2pt](o,A)
}
\tkzDrawCircles(P,M)
\tkzDrawPoints(P,M)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



What you have right now seems fine to me. You eventually need to get two strings of coordinates in different formats, and table.concat is the most efficient way of building such strings, so using two separate tables seems mostly unavoidable.

@MaxChernoff I have a lot of weaknesses with Lua, so I was wondering if I could avoid repetition.
